# how can i calculate Least-squares estimation $\theta$

Tags: regression, probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

suppose $E(y_i)=\theta(x_i+x_i^2)$. how can i calculate Least-squares estimation $\theta$ based on observations x:1,2,3 , y:4,8,14

Comment: Welcome! If it's a homework assignment you should let us know a little bit about what you have tried. It really does not help providing you directly the answer

Comment: Please do review http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info. This is your third such question without any attempt at making a start on the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1):

$$S=(\theta(1+1)-4)^2+(\theta(2+4)-8)^2+(\theta(3+9)-14)^2$$
$$=(2\theta-4)^2+(6\theta-8)^2+(12\theta-14)^2$$
$$=4\theta^2-16\theta+16
+36\theta^2-96\theta+64
+144\theta^2-336\theta+196$$
$$=184\theta^2-448\theta+276
$$
differetntiation
$$\frac{dS}{d\theta}=368\theta-448$$
zero derivation
$$
368\theta-448 = 0$$
means
$$
\theta = \frac{448}{368}=\frac{28}{23}
$$

Comment: Please don't offer complete numerical solutions to what appears to be homework. See the discussion of homework-like questions in the [help/on-topic]